# Upload to custom PyPi repo with Windows System User

Tags: python, bamboo, setup.py, build-server

I've got a Windows build server, where the build agent runs as the system user. Another user is not possible.

I want to upload a python egg to our own PyPi repository with

```
python setup.py sdist upload -r $RepoName
```

but this does not work since the ".pypirc" file cannot be found, because of the system user. If I use another user by hand it works fine.

Is there any possibility to tell the python setup tool, where the ".pypirc" file can be found?

Kind regards,
 secana

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good article:  https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/distributing-packages/

In general:

- Install twine
- Create necessary files
- Run twine